# Can't Access into LAN using Guest Account

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows7, and disabled internet access for guest user. I have 50+ PC and all are worked good except few. Now i got problem that a guest user can't access into LAN where this PC can access into LAN using Administrator. So what's the solution of this?

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: *and disabled internet access for guest user* How exactly did you do that?